# Filter the data where status ='pending ' in listing in firebase using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

I am creating admin panel in website and I am using firebase as a database in backend.I am able to display listing where onclick of accept status of listing get changed to 'accepted' but the thing is when status get change to accepted then listing in display should get filter and display only pending listing

pl.js

```
var firebaseheadingRef = firebase.database().ref().child("user");
function accept(userId) {
  var nodeRef = firebase.database().ref("/user/" + userId + "/listing/status");
  return nodeRef.set('accept');
} 

function reject(userId) {
  var nodeRef = firebase.database().ref("/user/" + userId + "/listing/status");
  return nodeRef.set('reject');
} 

firebaseheadingRef.on('child_added',datasnapshot=>{

   var title= datasnapshot.child("listing").child("title").val();
   var userid= datasnapshot.child("username").val();
   var type= datasnapshot.child("listing").child("title").val();
   var publisheddate= datasnapshot.child("listing").child("publish").val();
   var expirydate= datasnapshot.child("listing").child("expire").val();
   $("#tablebody").append("<tr><td>"+title+"</td><td>"+userid+"</td><td>"+type+"</td><td>"+publisheddate+"</td><td><button type=button id=accept onclick=accept('" + datasnapshot.key + "')>Accept</button><button type=button onclick=reject('" + datasnapshot.key + "')>Reject</button></td></tr>");

  });
```

should display filter listing where status = pending

Database

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful to add a picture of your database to understand a bit more about the structure

Comment: I have added the database

Answer (score 0):

You can use the orderByChild method along with the equalTo method to sort the children by status property

```
firebaseheadingRef.orderByChild("/listing/status").equalTo("pending")
.on('child_added',datasnapshot=> 
{
    //Enter your code here
});
```

Try changing the line

```
var firebaseheadingRef = firebase.database().ref().child("user");
```

to

```
var firebaseheadingRef = firebase.database().ref('/user');
```

Comment: its not working it show all the listing If any another method is there then please tell me

Comment: please tell me is any other method